# Windows 10 some application plus Task Manager not responding

Tags: windows-10, freeze

If some application is not responding, Task Manager can show whats the problem and terminate that process. But what if some application is not responding, and Task Manager is not responding too?

I use Ctrl+Alt+Del to bring up Task Manager again then there will be second/third... Task Managers, all of them are not reponding.

Sometimes the not reponding application is the Task Bar which make the system fully not usable. Sometimes the Task Bar is still working and I can start other programs like a command line window which means the source of the problem is not disks whose problem will make most new program not responding.

The problem still happen after reboot. Duration between episodes range from hours to days. Duration of a single episode can last several minutes and self recovered, or may never self recover and a reboot is needed. The HDD LED is not always on during the episode which means the disks are not the source.

What to do with this situation? Is there system log that I can check to find out the problem, or if I can start a command line window can I use some commands to check/kill processes?

Comment: Run Reliability History (Control Panel, Security and Maintenance).  What errors do you see there?

Comment: @ John That's so great. Now the problem is that information there seems can't get a solution. Every item's hang type number is different. BTW do you know how to prevent Windows to send report upon each ANR events since I found that every evet is sent to MS...

Comment: Reports should be sent to MS so that problems can be fixed.  We cannot help here unless we know what the error is. Please post the error names of two or three very recent errors.

Comment: A solution work for me is to just close the ANR programs with the close button on the up right corner of the program. The root of the problem seems to be Explorer, since when I force close all Resource Manager windows, the freezing is released

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For ***Is there system log that I can check to find out the problem...***

- You can check the **`Event Viewer`** and the log files in: 
  **`C:\Windows\System32\Winevt\Logs`**

```bat
"%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools\Event Viewer.lnk"
```

---

- To start Event Viewer : **`%windir%\system32\eventvwr.msc /s`**

How to use/find log in [Event Viewer](https://www.digitalmastersmag.com/magazine/tip-of-the-day-how-to-find-crash-logs-on-windows-10/)

---

> For ***if I can start a command line window can I use some commands to check/kill processes?***
>   - This is for loop check, you can save and use to check and this will to kill the process:
>
> ---

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set "_findstr=%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe - "
set "_timeout=%__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /t 10"
set "_taskkill=%__APPDIR__%taskkill.exe /f /im"

set "_wmic=%__APPDIR__%\wbem\wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime /value "
set "_tasklist=%__APPDIR__%tasklist.exe /nh /fi "status eq not responding""
>nul %__APPDIR__%chcp.com 1252 && %__APPDIR__%mode.com 64,4 & cd /d "%~dp0"

:loop
for /f tokens^=2^delims^=^=^. %%i in ('call !_wmic! ^| call !_findstr:-^=[0-9]!')do set "_dt=%%i" && (
call set "_now=[ !_dt:~0,4!/!_dt:~4,2!/!_dt:~6,2! !_dt:~8,2!:!_dt:~10,2! ]" && @color 9F & cls & echo/ 
set "_msg=!_now! All process running ok^!!" && echo/ && title <nul & title !__CD__!%~nx0 ^|^| !_now! )

for /f tokens^=1 %%I in ('call !_tasklist!')do echo/%%I|call !_findstr:-= \.exe! >nul && (   
echo/ !_now! %%I not responding^!! && >nul call !_taskkill! "%%~I" && call!_timeout! & cls
color f4 & goto :loop ) || (echo[ !_msg! && call !_timeout! & cls && echo/ && goto :loop )
```

---

- Same code in conventional formatting:

---

```bat
@echo off 

cd /d %__APPDIR__%
>nul chcp.com 1252
mode con: cols=64 lines=4
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

:loop
for /f "tokens=2 delims==." %%i in ('.\wbem\wmic.exe OS Get localdatetime /value ^|findstr [0-9]
') do set "_date=%%i" && (
   call set "_now=[ !_date:~0,4!/!_date:~4,2!/!_date:~6,2! !_date:~8,2!:!_date:~10,2! ]" 
   @color 9F
   cls 
   echo/ 
   set "_msg=!_now! All process running ok^!!" 
   echo/ 
   title <nul
   title !__CD__!%~nx0 ^|^| !_now!
   )

for /f "tokens=1" %%I in ('tasklist.exe /nh /fi "status eq not responding"
') do echo/%%~I|findstr  \.exe >nul && (
   echo[ !_now! %%I not responding^!!
   timeout 3 >nul 
   >nul taskkill /f /im "%%~I"
   cls
   color f4
   goto :loop 
   ) || (
   echo[ !_msg!
   timeout 10
   cls
   echo/
   goto :loop 
   )
```

---

Answer (score 0):

some application isn't reacting, Task Manager can show whats the issue and end that cycle. In any case, imagine a scenario where some application isn't reacting, and Task Manager isn't reacting as well.

I use Ctrl+Alt+Del to raise Task Manager again then there will be second/third... Undertaking Managers, every one of them are not reponding.

Once in a while the not reponding application is the Task Bar which make the framework completely not usable. At times the Task Bar is as yet working and I can begin different projects like an order line window which implies the wellspring of the issue isn't plates whose issue will make most new program not reacting.

The issue actually occur after [reboot](https://techspunky.com/how-to-view-crash-logs-in-windows-10/). Length between scenes range from hours to days. Span of a solitary scene can most recent a few minutes and self recuperated, or may never self recuperate and a reboot is required. The HDD LED isn't generally on during the scene which implies the plates are not the source.